# Using Python ArcGIS for Developers without using Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, arcgis-online, html, web

I want to create an ArcGIS map in Python, add layers to it based on data taken from a .csv file, and then display the map in a webpage.

Unfortunately, every Python tutorial I could find about the ArcGIS for developers needed to use something called a Jupyter Notebook. As far as I can tell, this would not work well with all the preexisting Python files I use in my project in other IDE's. I also do not like the idea of using an online IDE.

I have already successfully gotten the Python ArcGIS library in another IDE (PyCharm), and it is able to print out data and do most things normally. Except I can't find any way to actually visually display the maps or insert them into a webpage.

Am I going about this wrong, and is it impossible to avoid the Jupyter notebook? If not, how can I create an ArcGIS map and display it in a webpage in Python?

I'm very new to GIS.

Comment: 2 things: 1) I believe you're talking about `ArcGIS Python API`, not "Python ArcGIS for Developers". 2) I'm not 100% certain, but I believe the nice map output you see in the samples is dependent on Jupyter. Per this [topic](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html#ui) you can install notebooks into PyCharm and get the notebook output. in your IDE. You don't need to fire up a full Notebook on your local client or use a webbased one (like ArcGIS Online Notebooks)

Comment: From a cursory look at the API documentation, you may be looking for the [`arcgis.mapping.WebMap`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.mapping.toc.html#webmap) class.  The documentation notes that the [`arcgis.gis.GIS.map`](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.gis.toc.html#gis) widget that is used in the examples I looked at is for use in Jupyter  Notebooks only.